# How to create an array from elements located in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a problem which is seems super easy. I can't create an array from values located in an array. I console.logged the values but I struggle with creating an array from them. I will appreciate any help. The data is from mockapi.

```
console.log(database);
const dataLenght = 10;
const myData = [];
let lastData = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
  const showMe = [];
  const obj = database[i];
  myData.push(database[i].amount);
  showMe.push(database[i].amount)
  console.log(showMe)
  console.log(myData[i]);   
}
```

Comment: can you give ass all example and add comments, this part very small

Comment: From your code, the amount data should be able to add into the `myData` array. Are the lines `console.log(showMe);` and `console.log(myData[i]);` logging out the expected result?

Comment: yes I know is really small ..in the beginning I basically fetched data from mockapi...Unfortunately I had some problems with adding this part to stack overflow - that's why I cutted code to essential part. My problem is solved thank you everyone for initiative to help me :) RayChan - yes I got results but separately (12 values) not in array - what was my problem :)

Comment: If you observe the `myData` array outside of the for-loop, you should see an array containing 12 items. The reason why the two lines of log only outputted 1 item each is because you created a new `showMe` array in every iteration. Although you push an item into the `showMe` array, it will contain 1 item only as you are creating a new array each time and you push 1 item into it inside the for-loop block. For the logging about `myData[i]`, as you are accessing the i-th item in the `myData` array, as a result, you will also see just one item being logged to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
console.log(database);
const myData = [];
for (let i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
  myData.push(database[i].amount);
}
console.log(myData);
```

Comment: thank you very much! it worked! so I made it much more coplicated as it was ... thank you again <3 I've struggled with it for last 3 hours :P

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to map the `amount` property of a each single record to a different array.

If this is your problem, it can be solved with one line:

```
const myData = database.map(record => record.amount)
```

If this, instead, is not the case, please add some details to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is create a new array that consists in all the values in an existing array (in this case the `database` array) you can use the `map` method. This method is available in any JavaScript array. [More about map here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Then you could solve it just like this

`const myData = database.map(databaseItem => databaseItem.amount)`

The `map` method iterates through each item of the array, applying a callback function that is passed to it. All the values that get returned by that function are added to the new array (in our case the `myData` array). So in this example the `amount` property of each item inside the `database` array is added to `myData`.